# Using 3D RANSAC to estimate the 3D affine transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, affinetransform, ransac, image-registration

I am trying to register two volumeetric images(`img1` and `img2`). The size of the `img1` is `40x40x24`. The size of the `img2` is `64 x64x11`.
So far, I have extracted their features (`vol1` and `vol2`, the same size as the images) and then matched them.

Now, I have a set of corresponding points in two feature volumes that is stored in pairs which is a matrix of size `100x6` (every row of pairs is `[x, y, z, X, Y, Z]` where `(x,y,z)` are the coordinates of a voxel in `vol1` and `[X Y Z]` is the coordinates of corresponding voxel in `vol2`).

Now, I am trying to use RANSAC algorithm to estimate the 3D affine transform, T. I have written the below code, but I think there is a problem with it because when I get the output transform T and multiply it by a sample voxel coordinates from vol1, I get some negative coordinates!!!

Below is my implementation for 3D RANSAC algorithm. I have used 2D RANSAC implementation in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC). Please let me know if you see any problem.

```
function [bp] = ransac(data,bpI,iter,num,distThresh) 
 % data: a nx6 dataset with #n data points
 % num: the minimum number of points. Here num=4. 
 % iter: the number of iterations
 % distThresh: the threshold of the distances between points and the fitting line
 % inlierRatio: the threshold of the number of inliers 
 % bpI : Initialized affine transform model

  number = size(data,1); % Total number of points
 bestInNum = 0; % Best fitting line with largest number of inliers

 % Initial parameters for best model (affine transform)
 % Affine transform : T = [bp1, bp2, bp3, bp4; bp5, bp6, bp7, bp8; bp9, bp10, bp11, bp12;] 
 bp1 = bpI(1,1); bp2 = bpI(1,2); bp3 = bpI(1,3); bp4 = bpI(1,4); 
 bp5 = bpI(1,5); bp6 = bpI(1,6); bp7 = bpI(1,7); bp8 = bpI(1,8);
 bp9 = bpI(1,9); bp10 = bpI(1,10); bp11 = bpI(1,11); bp12 = bpI(1,12);

 for i=1:iter
 % Randomly select 4 points
     idx = randperm(number,num); sample = data(idx,:); 

     % Creating others which is the data that does not contain data in sample
     idxs =  sort(idx, 'descend'); % Sorting idx   
     others = data;
     for n = 1:num
         others(idxs(1,n), :) = []; 
     end

     x1 = sample(1,1); y1 = sample(1,2); z1 = sample(1,3);
     x2 = sample(2,1); y2 = sample(2,2); z2 = sample(2,3);
     x3 = sample(3,1); y3 = sample(3,2); z3 = sample(3,3);
     x4 = sample(4,1); y4 = sample(4,2); z4 = sample(4,3);

     X1 = sample(1,4); Y1 = sample(1,5); Z1 = sample(1,6);
     X2 = sample(2,4); Y2 = sample(2,5); Z2 = sample(2,6);
     X3 = sample(3,4); Y3 = sample(3,5); Z3 = sample(3,6);
     X4 = sample(4,4); Y4 = sample(4,5); Z4 = sample(4,6);

     B = [X1; Y1; Z1; X2; Y2; Z2; X3; Y3; Z3; X4; Y4; Z4];

     A = [
         x1, y1, z1, 1, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
         0 , 0 , 0, 0, x1, y1, z1, 1, 0, 0 ,0, 0;
         0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, x1, y1, z1, 1;
         x2, y2, z1, 1, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
         0 , 0 , 0, 0, x2, y2, z2, 1, 0 , 0 ,0, 0;
         0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, x2, y2, z2, 1;
         x3, y3, z3, 1, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
         0 , 0 , 0, 0, x3, y3, z3, 1, 0 , 0 ,0, 0;
         0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, x3, y3, z3, 1;
         x4, y4, z4, 1, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
         0 , 0 , 0, 0, x4, y4, z4, 1, 0 , 0 ,0, 0;
         0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0 , 0 , 0, 0, x4, y4, z4, 1
         ];

     cbp =  A\B; % calculating best parameters of the model (affine transform)
     T = [reshape(cbp',[4,3])'; 0, 0, 0, 1]; % Current affine transform matrix

     % Computing other points in the dataset that their distance from the
     % calculated model is less than the threshold.
     numOthers = size(others,1);
     inliers = [];
     for j = 1:numOthers
         % b = T a     
         d = others(j,:); % Explanation: d = [ax, ay, az, bx, by, bz]
         a = [d(1,1:3), 1]'; % Explanation a = [ax, ay, az]'
         b = [d(1,4:6),1]'; % b = [bx, by, bz]'
         cb = T*a; % Calculated b
         dist = sum((cb-b).^2);
         if(dist<=distThresh)
                  inliers = [inliers; d];        
         end
     end

     numinliers = size(inliers,1);
     % Update the number of inliers and fitting model if better model is found     
     if (numinliers >=  bestInNum)
         % Better model is estimated
          bestInNum = numinliers;
          bp1 = cbp(1,1); bp2 = cbp(2,1); bp3 = cbp(3,1); bp4 = cbp(4,1);
          bp5 = cbp(5,1); bp6 = cbp(6,1); bp7 = cbp(7,1); bp8 = cbp(8,1);
          bp9 = cbp(9,1); bp10 = cbp(10,1); bp11 = cbp(11,1); bp12 = cbp(12,1); 
          bp = [bp1, bp2, bp3, bp4, bp5, bp6, bp7, bp8, bp9, bp10, bp11, bp12];
     end
 end

 bp
end
```

Comment: I suggest providing a small sample case (even random data) to test against.

Comment: For rigid transformation estimation, the [typical solution uses SVD (Horn's method / umeyama algorithm, etc.)](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/svd_rot.pdf).